# GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri changing over time

Tags: azure, uwp, adal

We are developing an UWP app using ADAL authentication in Azure. We have configured our client in Azure Portal with the Redirect URI taken from the result of this method:

```
Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri()
```

It was working at the beginning, but now we've noticed that the URI generated by that method has changed. Therefore our login with ADAL does not worked anymore, stating that

> The reply address 'ms-app://s-1-15-2-104.......' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application.

Of course, we added the new value of the URI to the client configuration, and it worked, but after a day or two it has changed again. I think this is not the right way to update the Azure configuration every couple of days.

How can we ensure that the result of *GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri* stays unchanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri` uses your app's SID to construct the URL. I'm not sure of the exact mechanics of it, but if you are still developed the app, especially in a team, the SID can change.

One way to ensure that it remains fixed, is to create the Application in the Windows Dashboard and associate the app with the Store:
From Visual Studio - right click on the Project and select **Store->Associate app with the store**.

You don't have to submit, but associating the app will update the package.appxmanifest with the real values from the Dashboard and they will persist across developers.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker):

> To support SSO, the online provider must allow you to register a redirect URI in the form ms-app://appSID, where appSID is the SID for your app. You can find your app's SID from the app developer page for your app, or by calling the GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri method.